# C++ : Getting HTTP status code from a URL

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on a application where-in i have to hit a URL and get the HTTP status code returned from that URL. Currently I am using WININET functions to achieve this. The code to achieve this:

hOpen = InternetOpenA("MYAPP", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
hFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hOpen, url.c_str() , NULL, 0,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
HttpQueryInfoA(hFile,HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,(void*)buffer,&dwBufLen,NULL);

I did some checks to see the performance and i can see that on average a hit is taking about 300 milli-seconds. As i will be making multiple hits, the total time comes to about 8-10 sec which is slowing down the whole application.

Also the same is achieved on MAC is about 100 milli-seconds or so(i am using COCOA).

So are there any other APIs on WIN which i can use to get this faster?

Thanks in advance,
Amit

Comment: You could use the boost::asio library. It may be faster.

Comment: Have you done any packet sniffing to see how long the actual URL retrieval takes.  The time taken is dependent on the URL.

Comment: actually we cant include any other library.. so i have to depend upon standard C++ calls...

Comment: Then try WinHTTP as mentioned below. Or if that is not fast enougth you maybe have to build your own HTTP library on top the windows stack.

Answer (score 2):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is another option. It is actually platform independent. The thing that you might not like with this library is that you will need some extra DLLs.

Comment: The 'easy interface' of libcurl is simple and support everything what you describe, look at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

WinHTTP is the other major Win32 HTTP API.  It is designed more for servers and clients without UI and thus may be faster.